# What is the difference between tild and eval to find user home

Tags: bash

What is the difference between these two commands to find the user home-

```
$(eval echo ~<username>)

echo ~/
```

are there any scenario when both return different results?

Comment: The `eval` approach introduces security risk. If someone can convince the sysadmin (or automated tooling that's creating accounts) to make them a user account with a home directory whose name contains the literal string `$(rm -rf ~)`, guess what you just did by running that command?

Comment: The other thing is that putting the `eval` inside `$()` both makes things slower and also causes _additional_ security risk, because it runs the result of that command substitution _as a command itself_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tilde expansion is done by the shell before executing the command. So in both cases, the home directory becomes the argument to `echo`.

`eval` re-evaluates its arguments. So if the home directory contains any characters that have special meaning to the shell, these will be interpreted. For instance, if the user's home directory were `/home/$foo`,

```
echo ~username
```

would display the pathname with the literal `$foo` in it, but

```
eval echo ~username
```

would replace `$foo` with the value of the `foo` variable.

Next, putting `$()` around a command means that the output of the command is substituted into the command line, and then the command line is executed. So

```
$(echo ~username)
$(eval echo ~username)
```

will both try to execute the home directory as a command, which will get an error because directories aren't executable programs. But if you meant that this is being used as an argument, e.g.

```
cd $(echo ~username)
```

vs

```
cd ~username
```

There should be little difference. The only difference would be if the home directory pathname contains whitespace or wildcard characters, because these are processed after `$()` substitution. This problem can be avoided by quoting:

```
cd "$(echo ~username)"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation